# What grammar construction is used here: "Nous avons du parler"?

Tags: grammaire

For the Coffee Break French (a podcast that teaches French) [season 3 episode 11](http://traffic.libsyn.com/coffeebreakfrench/cbf-311-basic.mp3), at the 10:15 mark, I think I hear the following:

> Cette semaine, en cours, nous avons du parler de notre routine quotidienne.

I may have gotten some of the words incorrect, but I definitely hear "nous avons du parler".

I have never seen this construction before. I have seen de + infinitive before, but never du + infinitive. Can someone explain what construction is being used here, so I can Google it and learn about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **dû** not **du**. Dû is the past participle of the verb "devoir", so the tense of "nous avons dû" is passé composé.

> We had to talk about our daily routine.

Answer (score 3):

Note that while not used in the sentence you heard, *du* + infinitive is somewhat possible in French, when the infinitive is actually (used as) a noun representing something uncountable. For example:

- *Les narines devaient être dans la même situation, parce que l’odeur monte aussi ; et il les fallait près de la bouche, parce qu’elles nous aident beaucoup à juger **du boire et du manger**.*
  Génie du christianisme - Chateaubriand
- *Les premières leçons de la vue, du goût, du toucher, du marcher **et du parler.***
  Harmonies de l'enfance - Bernardin de Saint Pierre

Comment: This is interesting! I never knew an infinitive could sometimes be used as a noun!

Comment: Well, technically, the infinitive is the nominal form (or mode) of a verb. http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/infinitif.php

Answer (score 2):

To complete Stéphane's answer (I can not comment yet), you can use it to mean 'had to':

> J'ai dû + inf
>   Tu as dû + inf
>   Il a dû + inf
>   Nous avons dû + inf
>   Vous avez dû + inf
>   Ils / elles ont dû + inf

"J'ai dû prendre le bus" for example :)